# Problem with recv() on a tcp connection

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, send, recv

I am simulating TCP communication on windows in C.
I have  sender and a receiver communicating.

The sender sends packets of specific size to the receiver. The receiver gets them and sends an ACK for each packet it received back to the sender.
If the sender didn't get a specific packet (they are numbered in a header inside the packet) it sends the packet again to the receiver.
Here is the getPacket function on the receiver side:

```
//get the next packet from the socket. set the packetSize to -1
//if it's the first packet.
//return: total bytes read
// return: 0 if socket has shutdown on sender side, -1 error, else number of bytes received
int getPakcet(char* chunkBuff, int packetSize, SOCKET AcceptSocket)
{
    int totalChunkLen = 0;
    int bytesRecv = -1;
    bool firstTime = false;

    if(packetSize == -1)
    {
        packetSize = MAX_PACKET_LENGTH;
        firstTime = true;
    }

    int needToGet = packetSize;

    do
    {
        char* recvBuff;
        recvBuff = (char*)calloc(needToGet, sizeof(char));

        if(recvBuff == NULL)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation problem\n");
            return -1;
        }

        bytesRecv = recv(AcceptSocket, recvBuff, needToGet, 0);

        if(bytesRecv == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "recv() error %ld.\n", WSAGetLastError());
            totalChunkLen = -1;
            return -1;
        }

        if(bytesRecv == 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "recv(): socket has shutdown on sender side");
            return 0;
        }
        else if(bytesRecv > 0)
        {
            memcpy(chunkBuff + totalChunkLen, recvBuff, bytesRecv);
            totalChunkLen += bytesRecv;
        }

        needToGet -= bytesRecv;
    }
    while((totalChunkLen < packetSize) && (!firstTime));

    return totalChunkLen;
}
```

I use `firstTime` because for the first time the receiver doesn't know the normal package size that the sender is going to send to it, so I use a `MAX_PACKET_LENGTH` to get a package and then set the normal package size to the number of bytes I have received.

My problem is the last package.
It's size is less than the package size.
So lets say last package size is 2 and the normal package size is 4.
So `recv()` gets two bytes, continues to the while condition, then `totalChunkLen < packetSize`  because `2<4` so it iterates the loop again and the gets stuck in `recv()` because it's blocking because the sender has nothing to send.

On the sender side I can't close the connection because I didn't get ACK back, so it's kind of a deadlock. The receiver is stuck because it's waiting for more packages but sender has nothing to send.

I don't want to use a timeout for `recv()` or to insert a special character to the package header to mark that it is the last one.

What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using TCP to communicate between your receiver and transmitter and TCP is a stream-oriented protocol.  That is you put a stream of bytes in one end and you get the stream out on the other end, in order and with no loss.  There is no guarantee that each send() will match a recv() on the other end as the data may be broken up for various reasons.

So if you do the following with a TCP connection:

```
char buffer[] = "1234567890";
send(socket, buffer, 10, 0);
```

And then on the receiver:

```
char buffer[10];
int bytes = recv(socket, buffer, 10, 0);
```

bytes can be anywhere between 0 and 10 when recv() returns.

TCP runs over IP which is a datagram oriented protocol.  This is why the TCP implementation can assume that when it sends a datagram it will receive the entire datagram on the other end (or possibly not, or receive it out-of-order).  If you want to simulate that you have at least two options:

1. Add framing to your TCP messages so you can extract packets from it.  This involves adding things like the size of the packet to a header that you send into the stream.  It would be kind of meaningless to use this for simulating TCP as all your packets would always arrive, always in order and already using the underlying TCP flow control/congestion avoidance mechanisms.
2. Use a datagram protocol such as UDP.  This would be closer to the IP layer that TCP runs over.

You should probably go with option 2 but if you want to go the framing route over TCP you can e.g. (rough quick code follows):

```
// We do this to communicate with machines having different byte ordering
u_long packet_size = htonl(10); // 10 bytes packet
send(socket, &packet_size, 4, 0); // First send the frame size
send(socket, buffer, 10, 0); // Then the frame
```

Receiving end:

```
u_long packet_size; // Hold the size of received packet
int bytes_to_read = 4; // We send 4 bytes on the wire for size and expect 4
int nresult; // hold result of recv()
char *psize = &packet_size; // Point to first byte of size
while( bytes_to_read ) // Keep reading until we have all the bytes for the size
{
  nresult = recv(socket, psize, bytes_to_read, 0);
  if(nresult==0) deal with connection closed.
  bytes_to_read -= nresult;
  psize += nresult;
}
packet_size = ntohl(packet_size);
// Now we know the packet size we can proceed and read it similar to above
```

Comment: is this solution appropriate if we have packets with different sizes each time? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The concept to keep in mind with low-level socket programming is that you are exchanging a bunch of bytes with no structure imposed by the transport.  It is up to you to implement a protocol that does message delineation, either by putting the total length of what you consider a "message" at the start, by using a delimiter byte or sequence which you check in the received buffer, or by closing the connecting at the end (the latter looks easiest but is not the best solution, as you will want to reuse the connection in a real-world program as setting it up is expensive).

If this looks to complicated (and it is indeed not always easy), you need to look for a library that encapsulates this work for you, for example allowing you to send and receive an object which will be serialized, delineated and deserialized by the library code.  But the work needs to be done and it will not be the transport layer doing it for you.

One small remark about the code shown:  Your creating a memory leak with your multiple receive buffer allocations...

Comment: you are right about the memory leak, forgot to free. and also you are right about that i need to chose a certain way to deal with it. my only problem is that i am limited by the requirements, so i was looking for a specific solution for this situation, but it seems that i can't do it otherwise without making any assumptions

Comment: Maybe you should elaborate on the requirements.  If the goal is simulation of TCP, then message delineation is just not part of the game.  The size of each packet will be known as part of the protocol, and ack'd by the receiver.  But a single TCP packet could even contain the end of one and start of another 'application' message.  Which is way the application needs more info.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the amount of data in each packet at the beginning (e.g. the first 2 bytes can specify packet size), or pad the last packet so it's the same size as the others.

Edit: If you really want to 'simulate' the TCP then you should probably be using recvfrom() and sendto(), and then you receive the data in whole packets of varying sizes, and you won't have this problem.

Comment: I can't transfer anything other than the 1 byte packet header (the number of the packat) and the packet data itself

Comment: thanks tev, but isn't recvfrom() and sendto() limited to DGRAM only ?

Comment: But this is what you want, no? recv() with a connection oriented socket is using TCP/IP. If you want to simulate TCP (if I understand correctly, you want to implement the protocol by hand) then using TCP is kind of cheating. But also you'd want to simulate the encapsulation as well, including the IP header etc which includes the total length [(see headers here)](http://nmap.org/book/tcpip-ref.html)

Answer (score 1):

Your receiver needs to be told by the sender that it has finished. This can be done by either first sending the size of the data the receiver can expect, always send the same amount of data, or send a sentinel value to indicate there will be no more bytes following. The sender could also close the connection when it is finished sending in which case recv will return 0 when there is nothing left to be read and it detects the connection has been closed.

Comment: thanks dave, but again,my requirements are that i can't transfer anything to the receiver beside the packet number, so i can't tell him which size to expect or send any sentinel data. also, about the closing the connection, it's an option, but the probelm is that the sender needs to get ACK or NACK from the receiver. lets say i close the connection, and then send an NACK, the sender will have to open the connection again only to send the packet that was lost. i'm very limited about what i can transfer in the communication channel.

Comment: I'm assuming you haven't posted all your code so I can only guess to the protocol you are trying to implement. I'm not sure what you are trying to ACK. However, TCP ACKs are handled by the socket implementation and you don't need to be sending them. If you are sending ACKs as part of your own protocol, that's something different. With TCP you will receive everything that is sent or you will receive an error. If you've received all your data without error, it has already been ACKed at the TCP level. If the sender sends without error, it knows it has all been received.